# Is there any efficient way to compute the exponentiation of an fractional base and fractional exponent?

Tags: solidity, evm

First off - not the same question as [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10425/is-there-any-efficient-way-to-compute-the-exponentiation-of-a-fraction-and-an-in) (which is great). I need the exponent to be fractional as well. Something like 2.5^0.75

Comment: @MaiaVictor Im adding a bounty for anyone who can come up with something here.

Note: The Bancor equations most likely need this as well for their `connector-weight` exponent

Comment: Well you can read how bancor done this in their smart contract - https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts/blob/master/solidity/contracts/converter/BancorFormula.sol#L289

Comment: this is good. I've asked the author to explain how it works

Comment: You can see how it's done in C also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174239/how-does-the-pow-function-work. It  looks somewhat alike.

Comment: @ZMitton damn I wasn't notified. A little bit late. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code of a good solution:

```
function power(uint256 _baseN, uint256 _baseD, uint32 _expN, uint32 _expD) internal view returns (uint256, uint8) {
    assert(_baseN < MAX_NUM);

    uint256 baseLog;
    uint256 base = _baseN * FIXED_1 / _baseD;
    if (base < OPT_LOG_MAX_VAL) {
        baseLog = optimalLog(base);
    }
    else {
        baseLog = generalLog(base);
    }

    uint256 baseLogTimesExp = baseLog * _expN / _expD;
    if (baseLogTimesExp < OPT_EXP_MAX_VAL) {
        return (optimalExp(baseLogTimesExp), MAX_PRECISION);
    }
    else {
        uint8 precision = findPositionInMaxExpArray(baseLogTimesExp);
        return (generalExp(baseLogTimesExp >> (MAX_PRECISION - precision), precision), precision);
    }
}
```

Full working code at: https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/solidity-toolbox/blob/master/contracts/FractionalExponents.sol

**Some explanation**

A floating point number `x` can be represented in two numbers: `a/b`

```
 if x = a/b and y = c/d, then x ^ y = (a/b) ^ (c/d)
```

**The problem**

The problem is that if the a code is written as `(a/b) ^ (c/d)`, the accuracy of the result would be a mess. Because the division of `a/b` and `c/d` would smash the floating point.

Going into another try, the expression `(a/b) ^ (c/d)` could be evaluated as `a ^ (c/d) / b ^ (c/d)` or `(a^c + a^(1/d)) / (b^c + b^(1/d))`. 
The problem with this is that the powering `a` to `c` or even to `c/d` could easily overflow uint256! Even though, the final resulting value could be a small uint8. (this is explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10425/is-there-any-efficient-way-to-compute-the-exponentiation-of-a-fraction-and-an-in))

**The Solution**

There is an approximation for `x ^ y` as follow:

```
x ^ y  = e ^ (log(x) * y)
```

Actually, the method above depend on this equation to compute the power function. As follow:

```
(_baseN / _baseD) ^ (_expN /_expD) = e ^ (log(base) * exp)
```

Where `base = _baseN / _baseD` (note that FIXEX_1 that is used in the code, is just used to shift the number of left in order to provide better accuracy of the division.
And `exp = _expN /_expD`.

The key point here is calculating the `log(base) * exp` before powering to `e`, will prevent overflow compared to the early discussed formula the can easily produce overflow: `a ^ (c/d) / b ^ (c/d)` or `(a^c + a^(1/d)) / (b^c + b^(1/d))`.

However, for `optimalLog` vs. `generalLog` and `optimalExp` vs. `generalExp` that is used in the provided code, they is about calculating the `log` and `e ^` either in an optimal or an approximate calculation.

---

Thanks [leonprou](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/31572/leonprou) for his valuable comments on the question.

Comment: I gave you the check mark but you've removed some of the functions. Could you please include those so that this compiles?

Comment: I did not include the full code in the answer because it is quite long with 350+ lines of code. However, upon your request I created a file that contains only and all the needed functions at https://github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/solidity-toolbox/blob/master/contracts/FractionalExponents.sol .

Answer (score 1):

You may calculate `x^y` as `2^(y log_2 x)` using [ABDK Math 64.64](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol#L366) library, that has both: `2^x` and `log_2 x` functions implemented for binary fixed point numbers.  This way is especially efficient in case you need to calculate `x^y` multiple times for the same `x` but different `y`, because you may calculate `log_2 x` once and reuse.